# Web scraping Nodejs cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have to get content of `<script>` tag in website. But there are many `<script>` tags and with no `id` attribute. Cheerio doesn't get `<script>` tag content when I call it like this:

```
$('script').text()
```

or

```
.html();
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: `{xmlMode: true}` I believe is the workaround for this one (as a 2nd arg to cheerio.load).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$('script').html()`